# What's wrong with my regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a RegularExpressionValidator that validates a password field. The password must contain letters and at least 1 number and must be between 8 and 20 characters. Here's my validator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewPassword"
                ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w{8,20}$" ErrorMessage="Password must contain at least one digit and must be between 8 and 20 characters"
                Text="*" ValidationGroup="Passwords"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This works great in my development environment and when I works on my local machine but it doesn't work when I migrate it to the production environment. In the production environment, I must start off with a digit for it to pass. Our production environment is running a Win 2k8 R2 machine but I can't imaging that that would matter. I found another post in here saying that this expression would work so I tested it and indeed it did work...but only in my dev environment.
Can anyone see why, in my production environment, I have have to start off with a number for this to work? The number should be anywhere in the password.

Thanks

Comment: Your regular expression is fine. It could be the engine in asp.net works differently, but your expression is fine and should work as intended.

Comment: You're not using IE6 are you? http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug

Comment: What version, service pack, etc are your IIS and .Net framework in each environment?

Comment: Oh, and more importantly, is there any good reason to limit the password to 20 characters?  That frustrates me when I hit a site, and I want to use a pass phrase, but can't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(?=\w{8,20}$)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*
```

It relates to an IE6 bug, but it may still apply depending on the version of ASP.NET running on your production machine.

Comment: Interesting! Although it works in IE 6 when i'm accessing it locally and in Prod it fails. Maybe an authenticaion issue?